# How to call function in if statement and save return value

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I'm stuck in a simple question that I can't find an answer.
If want to call a function in an if statement. This is a function really challenging and it takes a long time to get response, how can I preserve the return value?

I explain the problem with an example:

- function

```py
def recursive:
    if .... :
      return value
    else:
      return False
```

recursive is an hypothetically function that takes a lot of time to generating response, that could be a value or just a simple boolean False.

- main

```py
...

if recursive():
  ...value? (make something with value return)
```

other method

```py
...

if recursive():
  value = recursive()
```

This other method will call the function 2 times and it takes too long time.

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you just `value = recursive()` and then `if (value) do whatever you want and have access to the value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.8 will add an operator to do exactly this (called the walrus operator `:=`), but unfortunately the closest thing you can do today is this

```py
value = recursive()
if value:
    pass  # do stuff with value
else:
    pass  # do other stuff with value
# can still do stuff with value here
```

If running on 3.8+, the following will be valid

```py
if value := recursive():
    pass  # do stuff with value
else:
    pass  # do other stuff with value
# can still do stuff with value here
```

Comment: The first method is completely fine as it calls the expensive function only once as well. `:=` is simply syntactic sugar.

Comment: Totally, I expect that they will yield identical bytecode. The debate over the inclusion of this operator is [long and storied](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19077731).